# FileReader "eats" each first letter

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, filereader, java-io

I have a code:

```
File readFile = new File("acc\\10001.txt");
protected void readData(File file){

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while(reader.read() != -1){
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Method is in constructor of the Main class. When starting the project, console shows (e.g.): "est" instead of "Test", "0001" instead of "10001".

It works for all strings and integers.

Each help is appreciated.

Comment: No, `(reader.read() != -1)` "eats" one character. Get rid of that and just use `readLine()` until it returns null.

Comment: when I use `while(reader.readLine() == null)` console doesn't return any char/number, when I use `while(reader.readLine() != null)` console returns only 5 of 10 lines included in my file

Comment: Store result of `readLine()` in variable and use that variable in your loop condition and loop body. You can write it like `String line = null; while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){ .. handle current line..}`.

Comment: OR use class like `Scanner` which internally caches values read via `has..XYZ..()` which later can be retrieved via methods like `nextLine()`. This way your code can look like `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(pathToFile)); while(scanner.hasNextLine()){ String line = scanner.nextLine(); ..handle current line.. }`.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks bro for resolve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet:

```
while(reader.read() != -1){
    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
}
```

reads one character every time the while condition is evaluated (`read()` gets invoked and [it reads next character](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()).

Change your code with better approach:

```
String line="";
while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) { //variable line gets assigned with value and then it's checked against null
    System.out.println(line);
}
```